# Can you reconfigure roles specified during installation in CentOS?

Tags: installation, centos5, yum, package-management

During installation of a couple of CentOS servers I selected the "Server" option in the package configuration screen at the end of the installation process.

It turns out that I only needed a clean base installation, without the options installed by the "Server" group.

I noticed that `yum grouplist` doesn't display this 'super role', but has some packages that seem related; probably sub-roles of the "Server" profile. I'm not sure which package belongs to this profile though..

Is there an easy way to remove all packages contained in this selection? Like a menu that displays the same profiles as shown during installation, or an option I can pass to yum for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Add/Remove Software" under the "Applications" menu to remove the individual server groups.   Otherwise, from the command line you can run 'yum groupremove "FTP Server" "Mail Server"', obviously you would want to include all of the Group names here, but I think you get the idea.  Please note that I use the quotation marks there because of the space in the group names.

Be careful and review what will be removed if you do this, as some of the servers are dependencies for things like "system-config-keyboard" and "mdadm".